# Measure of the Empty Set

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to learn measure theory by myself and I wanted to have some assurence of what I did. Also if anybody knows any easier way of proving this, it would be appreciated.

The question at hand gives a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, defines a function $m:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ that is countably additive over countable disjoint collections of sets in $\mathcal{A}$ and asks us to prove the following:

- $\exists \, A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $m(A) < \infty \; \Rightarrow \; m(\emptyset) = 0.$

First I defined a sequence of sets:

$$ E_1 = A $$
$$\forall \, n \geq 2 \, \,E_i = \emptyset $$

Clearly the sequence is pairwise disjoint and belongs to $\mathcal{A}$, so we can use the countable additivity property:

$$m(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} m(E_i) = \lim_{n \to \infty} m(A) + (n - 1) \, m(\emptyset) \tag{1}$$.

Here is where I'm having a little bit of trouble. My idea was this: From $(1)$ and the fact that $m(A) < \infty$ we have:

$$ 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} (n - 1)\, m(\emptyset)$$

Because $0 \leq m(\emptyset) \leq (n - 1) \, m(\emptyset), \, \, \forall \, n \geq 2$, if we use the squeeze theorem, we get that $m(\emptyset) = 0$.

Is this last part correct? Is there a more direct way of solving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By countable addivity, $\mu(A)+\mu(\varnothing)=\mu(A)$... Since $\mu(A)$ is finite, what does that tell us?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the squeeze theorem is working into your solution, but I agree that what you have is correct.  See @DonThousand's comment for a slightly more direct solution.

Comment: The ideia was, given the inequality $0 \leq m(\emptyset) \leq (n - 1) \, m(\emptyset)$ taking limits we get $0 \leq m(\emptyset) \leq 0 \Rightarrow m(\emptyset) = 0$.

Comment: @DonThousand The idea would be that the finiteness of $m(A)$ will allow us to subtract from both sides and arrive at the conclusion that $m(\emptyset) = 0$. My question would be how would you go from countable additivity to finite addivity without already knowing that the measure of some set is zero.

Comment: @GiordanoRibeiro There's an easy fix for that. Let $A_1=A$, $A_{n>1}=\varnothing$. By countable additivity, we have $$\mu(A)=\mu(A)+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\mu(\varnothing)$$By finiteness of $\mu(A)$, we have $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\mu(\varnothing)=0$$

Comment: I disagree with @DonThousand 's first comment : the finite additivity is only a consequence of countable additivity if $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$. The use of the squeeze theorem is a bit overkill : since $\mu(\emptyset)$ does not depend on $n$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}(n-1)\mu(\emptyset)$ is $+\infty$ if $\mu(\emptyset) >0$ .